# Array of Key->Value array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, d

I am starting with the D language (D2) and I am trying to do the following:

```
string[int] slice1 = [ 0:"zero", 1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three", 4:"four" ];
string[int] slice2 = [ 0:"zero", 1:"one", 2:"two"];

alias MySlice = string[int];
MySlice[] list;
list[] =slice1;
list[]=slice2;
writeln(list);
```

It compiles but the list stays empty. What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list[] = slice1;`

I guess you're expecting this to append `slice1` to the list, as in PHP. But the meaning in D is: "Assign `slice1` to each of the elements in the list." As your list has no elements, nothing is being changed.

For appending, use the `~=` operator:

`list ~= slice1;`

Answer (score 4):

MySlice[] is an array of string[int], i.e. each element of the variable 'list' is string[int]. If that's what you want, then the code should be something like

```
alias MySlice = string[int];
MySlice[] list;
list = [slice1];
list ~= [slice2];
writeln(list);
```

The result will be

```
[[0:"zero", 1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three", 4:"four"], [0:"zero", 1:"one", 2:"two"]]
```

If you want to join two arrays slice1 and slice2 in a single string[int] array, you need to iterate over each array and copy elements into list

```
alias MySlice = string[int];
MySlice list;
foreach (k, v; slice1)
  list[k] = v;
foreach (k, v; slice2)
  list[k] = v;
writeln(list);
```

And the result will be

```
[0:"zero", 4:"four", 1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three"]
```